# How to parse date String containing Locale

Tags: java, parsing, timezone, jodatime

I have a date String "Sat Jan 28 00:00:00 IST 2012" and I am trying to parse it using DateTimeFormatter of Joda. I have the following code, dont know where, it went wrong.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFmt = DateTimeFormat
            .forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:SS ZZZ yyyy");
DateTime dateTime = dateFmt.parseDateTime(dateString);
```

> Exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Sat Jan 28 00:00:00 IST 2012" is malformed at "IST 2012". Please help me to get thro this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but it is working if I use `SimpleDateFormat` instead of `DateTimeFormatter`.

CODE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:SS zzz yyyy";
        String dateString = "Sat Jan 28 00:00:00 IST 2012";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT);
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
        System.out.println(new DateTime(date));
        DateTimeFormatter dateFmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(FORMAT);
//      System.out.println(dateFmt.parseLocalDateTime(dateString));
//      System.out.println(dateFmt.parseDateTime(dateString));
        System.out.println(dateFmt.parseLocalTime(dateString));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`IST` is not recognized timezone by API, It can recognize only one of the timezone from [`getAvailableIds()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs%28%29)

Comment: if you meant Indian Standard Time then may be invoke `public static String[] getAvailableIDs(int rawOffset)` with `5.5` and see what it returns, there should be something like `Kolkatta/India` not sure, check it out

Comment: Hey, IST is there, I just tried printing all of them. `for (String string : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
   System.out.println(string);
  }`

Comment: then just replace `ZZZ` to `zzz`, as Matt suggested

Answer (score 1):

Use `zzz` (lowercase), not `ZZZ` (uppercase). From [the API docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

```
 z   time zone              text      Pacific Standard Time; PST
 Z   time zone offset/id    zone      -0800; -08:00; America/Los_Angeles
```